# Finding Intersection points using array, linspace and IF

Tags: arrays, matlab, coordinates, intersection, curves

I am plotting two equations against each other, I did this by creating a 2x100 array and a linspace. I have successfully plotted the curves, but I don't know how to find the values (of u and c) that they intersect at?

I have tried `intersect(,)`, `find(==)`, but they doesn't work with my problem, I think because it uses an if loop.

Here is my code:

```
clear all
A = 3;
B = 1.8;
d = 1;
c2 = 1;
c1 = 0.7;
s = 0.1;

c = linspace(0,1.5);
u = zeros(2,numel(c));

for i = 1:numel(c)
u(1,i)= c(i) / ((A/(c(i)+1))-(d*c(i)/(c(i)+c2))) ; 
u(2,i)= B*c(i) /(c(i)+c1)-s;
end

hold on
plot(c,u(1,:),'r');
plot(c,u(2,:),'g');
hold off
```

[image: graph]

Comment: First thing: you don't need a loop here: `u(1,:)= c ./ ((A./(c+1))-(d*c./(c+c2))) ; 
u(2,:)= B*c ./(c+c1)-s;`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are evaluating at discrete points, you have not *hit* a point where `u_1==u_2`. You can see the point where they are closest with

```
>> [diff_min, diff_min_index] = min(abs(u(1,:)-u(2,:)))

diff_min =

    0.0046


diff_min_index =

    65
>> hold on
>> plot(c(diff_min_index),u(1,diff_min_index))
>> hold off
```

Perhaps more helpfully, you can find the indices when `u_1-u_2` changes sign:

```
>> find(diff(sign(u(1,:)-u(2,:)))~=0)

ans =

     4    65
```

To find the intersection, you could define a function as the difference of your two functions `f=u_1 - u_2` and search for roots using the MATLAB function [`fzero`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html):
You could do this by defining your original functions as anonymous functions:

```
>> f1 = @(c) c./((A./(c+1)) - d*c./(c+c2)); 
>> f2 = @(c) B*c./(c+c1) - s;
>> f_diff = @(c) f1(c) - f2(c);
>> fzero(f_diff,0)

ans =

    0.0488

>> fzero(f_diff,1)

ans =

    0.9729
```

If the original functions are not available, one could use [`griddedInterpolant`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant-class.html).

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I used your last suggestion of making them into functions. Very kind, thank you for your time.

Comment: @StefaniNotti No problem, glad we could help. Please consider marking an answer as accepted. You can read more on the page [Help Center > Answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The low-cost version:

With this method I'm just looking at the nearest point before/after the intersection:

```
ind = find(diff([u(1,:)-u(2,:)]>0))
interx = c(ind);
```

The best option (IMO) is to use this method to approximate the intersection points and then use the **@Steve's solution** to determine a more precise solution.

```
for i = 1:length(interx)
fzero(f_diff,interx(i))
end
```

Comment: I like the loop and the *best* starting guess. You don't need the `~=0` in the find, since you have `>0`. (I guess also true in my use of `find` actually)